# How can you remove last parameter from a $_GET URL when using the QUERY_STRING?

Tags: php, parsing, url, parameters, query-string

Since I'm using a foreach loop, all the parameters are shown. I have several parameters which I want to include from my URL, but I want to remove the last parameter and it's value from automatically showing. The code is as follows:

```
 <?php   

$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$params = array();

foreach( $query as $param )
{ 
  list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
  echo $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
  echo "<br/>";
}

  echo "<br/> Total amount placed: ".$total = $_GET["total"];

?>
```

The URL is this one:

```
confirmation.php?betSlip=Juve&betSlip=Milan&total=0.43
```

As you can see the url consists of several items inside a betSlip parameter, and it consists the total of all items. I want to remove the total from displaying in the foreach loop and be able to display it only whenever I call it.

Thanks

Comment: I can't send betSlip as array. Is there any other alternative such as using a for loop and it stops before the last parameter?

Answer (score 1):

DavidDomain is right. You could alternatively unset just that specific key value pair in the array, if you can't guarantee it'll always be the last array element.

```
$params = $_GET;

unset($params['total']);

// $params is now array('betSlip' => 'Juve', 'betSlip' => 'Milan');
```

Comment: Sure, would be an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_pop` to remove the last element of the `$query` array. Given that `total` will always be the last param.

```
    $params = "betSlip=Juve&betSlip=Milan&total=0.43";
    $query  = explode('&', $params);
    array_pop($query); // remove the last element of $query
    $params = array();

    foreach( $query as $param )
    {
        list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
        echo $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    echo "<br/> Total amount placed: ".$total = $_GET["total"];
```

Comment: I can't send betSlip values as arrays since they contain other items in them. Is there any other alternative as leave the code the same, but maybe update the for loop to stop before the last parameter?